# Product of Numbers in Circle

Tags: probability, average

Consider the circle $\large\lambda$ of radius $1$ centered at $(1,1)$.

Say I drop a pin directly onto $(x,y) \in \large \lambda$.

What is the expected value of $xy$?

A part of me was like $1$ x $1 = \boxed1$.

Another part of me was like $\displaystyle \frac{1}{π} \int_0^2 \int_{1-\sqrt{1-(y-1)^2}}^{1+\sqrt{1-(y-1)^2}}xy\,dx\,dy=\boxed1$.

Another piece of me was like $\displaystyle \frac{1}{2π}\int_0^{2π}(\sin x+1)(\cos x+1)\,dx=\boxed1$ .

Here was the problem verbatim:

> Compute the expected value of the product of the coordinates of a point randomly selected on a circle of radius $1$ centered at the point $(1,1)$.

So my ideas were

1. Average the coordinates and multiply
2. Find the average over the circle
3. Find the average over the perimeter

And somehow all of them ended up with the same answer. Trippy.

Which one is correct? I felt that the problem was a bit vague.

Comment: I read the problem as asking for $E\{(x,y)\}$, that is, a multivariate expectation.

Comment: Oops. edited @SZN

Comment: Also, do you mean the *disk* centered at $(1,1)$? The circle is a set of measure zero in the plane.

Comment: um sure. isn't disk another word for circle @SZN

Comment: oh, i just searched it up. see that's the thing, if it were the circle, then i would use #3, and if it were the disc, i would use #2. and now that i think about it, #1 might be out of the question @SZN

Comment: No. The circle of radius $r$ centered at $(x_0,y_0)$ is the set $\{(x-x_0,y-y_0) \ | \ (x-x_0)^2 + (y - y_0)^2 = r^2\}$. The *open* disk of the same radius centered at the same point is the set $\{(x-x_0,y-y_0) \ | \ (x-x_0)^2 + (y - y_0)^2 < r^2\}$. The *closed* disk...$\{(x-x_0,y-y_0) \ | \ (x-x_0)^2 + (y - y_0)^2  \leq r^2\}$. Circles are boundaries of disks -- one dimensional sets.

Comment: When you speak of an "average," that requires you to assign "weights" to different parts of the circle. The most natural weighting is to say that arcs of equal length have equal weight. That corresponds to your second integral. You could come up with a different integral by weighting arcs differently. However, your first integral doesn't even do that. Your first integral takes the average of $xy$ over the entire disk (including interior points), where you've assigned equal weight to regions of equal area.

Comment: $\int_{0}^{2\pi}{1 \over 2\pi}\,\cos\left(\,\theta\,\right)\sin\left(\,\theta\,\right)\,\mathrm{d}\theta = 0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A point on the circle is a point of the form $(1+\cos \theta, 1+\sin \theta)$, so your second integral is the correct formulation of the problem.  As the trig functions average to zero over a period, the integral is $1$ as you say.